# youtube player api, create player api on click

Tags: php, api, youtube-api

I need help to create youtube player on click, because i have button when it click will create new section that have youtube player.

from what i know if on the first load, the setup of player api will be run great which is the player will create when triggered on load by youtube

this is my first load code (partly)

```html
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function(){
    vidModal = new YT.Player('vid-modal',{events: {'onReady': onPlayerReadyModal, 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChangeModal}, playerVars: playerDefaults});
        vidbgSlider  = new YT.Player('tv',{events: {'onReady': onPlayerReady, 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}, playerVars: playerDefaults});
        
        for (var i = 0; i < blockPlayerID.length; i++) { 
          blockPlayer[i] = new YT.Player(blockPlayerID[i],{events: {'onReady': onPlayerReadyBlock, 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChangeBlock}, playerVars: playerDefaults});
        }

  }
```

That all run well when web on first load...all player will create on that event "onYouTubePlayerAPIReady" but the problem is when i try to create another object player when triggered by button click...it can not :

```html
newPlayer = new YT.Player('newplayerID',{events: {'onReady': onPlayerReadyModal, 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChangeModal}, playerVars: playerDefaults});
```

after create that and call "loadVideoById" it's error said that loadVideoById is not a function, anyone have solution about this? seems that function just can be loaded one time...on web first load...thank you so much before!

Answer (score 0):

After couple days..i found my own solution, so when it click i just call again the "onYouTubePlayerAPIReady" function and make validation if the player is already create or not..if not then created it..and seems that not make any error on js..thank you!